# Overlay with words across multiple images

Tags: html, css

I am making a instagram type of feed and have a 4 images with a further 4 below those 4. I need to make a overlay which I can put words in front of all 8 images showing instagram followers and a link to their instagram.

I have most of it done but the overlay I cannot seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Josh

```html
<ul class="images">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="img/instagram/image-1.jpg" alt="Image Gallery" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="img/instagram/image-2.jpg" alt="Image Gallery" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello rJosh, please provide some sample code. It will make it easier to help :)

Comment: Hey, I went ahead and put some code that I am using. I didn't want to make it to big but there is a total of 8 separate images.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The code provided does not look like _*have most of it done*_ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o overlay div with position absolute covering the entire images container like the example....

```css
.images{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.overlay{
   position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.images:hover .overlay{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Image Gallery" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Image Gallery" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class='overlay'>
      <span>some text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? You can put whatever words in the overlay as you want. I used xs columns so you could see it fully.

```css
.overlay{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  z-index:10;
}
.overlay h2{
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="overlay">
<h2>Follow me on Insta</h2>
</div>
<div class="row images">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="Image Gallery" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="Image Gallery" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="Image Gallery" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="Image Gallery" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the below is what you need. I used flexboxes for layout.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  width: 500px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
}

.text:hover {
  border: thin solid red;
  animation: opac 0.3s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes opac {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row-sm-12 container">
  <div class="row-sm-3 item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <div class="text">Bla bla</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-sm-3 item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <div class="text">Bla bla</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-sm-3 item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <div class="text">Bla bla</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-sm-3 item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <div class="text">Bla bla</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-sm-3 item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <div class="text">Bla bla</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-sm-3 item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <div class="text">Bla bla</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-sm-3 item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <div class="text">Bla bla</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-sm-3 item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    <div class="text">Bla bla</div>
  </div>
</div>
```